# Do humble forms exist in Kansai-ben?

Tags: honorifics, kansai-ben

I know that Kansai-ben has a variety of strategies to express honorification. For instance, the honorific form of `use' in Kyōto-ben is 使いはる. My question is about whether 謙譲語 forms exist in Kansai varieties. How do speakers of Kyōto, Ōsaka, Kōbe, etc. varieties express what would be お使いする or 致す in 標準語?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot think of a Kansai-specific humble form, but I think ～さしてもらう (or ～させてもらう) is more commonly heard in Kansai-ben. (Strictly speaking, this may not be called a humble "form", but it's a humble expression anyway.) For example, a stereotypical Osakan merchant may say 見さしてもらいます instead of 拝見します.